# What does "pray" mean in phrases like "pray proceed"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, archaicisms

Is this an archaic form of "please proceed"? I have never heard in in speech but sometimes it appears in novels. My version of "The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes" is full of it, apparently in place of "please".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *NOAD* installed on my Mac Mini reported the following definition for *pray*.

> adverb formal or archaic
>   used as a preface to polite requests or instructions: *pray continue*.
>   • used as a way of adding ironic or sarcastic emphasis to a question: *and what, pray, was the purpose of that?*

In the first example, you can replace *pray* with *please*.

Similar definition is given by the [*Oxford Living Dictionaries*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pray).

Comment: That last form is, I think, a shortening of "pray tell"; which means pray is still used as a form of "please".

Comment: and what, pray, does "NOAD" stand for?

Comment: It stands for _New Oxford American Dictionary_.

Answer (score 10):

The word "pray" means to earnestly ask something of someone. Therefore, the phrase "pray proceed" could be interpreted as "Please, I beg of you, proceed".

In modern English, we often think of the term "pray" in a spiritual context, but the meaning is the same: to ask something of someone.

Comment: Dead right, +1.  Even nowadays in certain legal documents, the prayer is the  section that asks the Court to do something.

Answer (score 9):

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pray

pray 
    late 13c., "ask earnestly, beg," also "pray to a god or saint," from O.Fr. preier (c.900), from L. precari "ask earnestly, beg," from *prex (plural preces, gen. precis) "prayer, request, entreaty," from PIE base *prek- "to ask, request, entreat" (cf. Skt. prasna-, Avestan frashna- "question;" O.C.S. prositi, Lith. prasyti "to ask, beg;" O.H.G. frahen, Ger. fragen, O.E. fricgan "to ask" a question). Parenthetical expression I pray you, “please, if you will,” attested from 1510s, contracted to pray 16c.

Comment: In short, the dated pray for please is connected with French je vous prie.

Answer (score 1):

See also the version I like enough to consider using in conversation to stage a come back: *[Prithee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prithee) tell*. The etymology sheds some light on the sometimes sarcastic nature of *pray tell*.

Answer (score 1):

adverb
formal or archaic
1Used as a preface to polite requests or instructions: ladies and gentlemen, pray be seated

1.1Used as a way of adding ironic or sarcastic emphasis to a question: and what, pray, was the purpose of that?

From online Oxford English dictionary