# Etymology of 'inexorable' : What does 'out' + 'pray' mean?

Tags: etymology, ambiguity

> [inexorable (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=inexorable&searchmode=none)   
>       1550s, from Middle French inexorable and directly from Latin inexorabilis "that cannot be moved by entreaty," from in- "not, opposite of" (see [in-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in-&allowed_in_frame=0) (1)) + exorabilis "able to be entreated," from ***exorare* "to prevail upon,"** from ***ex-* "out"** (see [ex-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ex-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ***orare* "pray"** (see [orator](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=orator&allowed_in_frame=0)). ...
>
> exorable (adj.)   
>       1570s, "susceptible of being moved by entreaty" (a word much rarer than its opposite and probably existing now only as a back-formation from it), from Latin exorabilis "easily entreated, influenced by prayer," from exorare "to persuade" (see [inexorable](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inexorable&allowed_in_frame=0)) ...

1. What's the meaning of 'pray' as bolded above? Is it the modern one  of  prayer, or [the olden one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10057/50720)?

2. How did the 2 syntagma  (***ex-* "out"** + ***orare* "pray"**) combine to mean
***exorare* "to prevail upon,"**? I don't understand this key link in the etymology.

Comment: *Pray* = "entreat" (e.g."beg" someone [to give or do something). *Prevail upon*  = "Persuade" someone (to give or do something)--typically by entreaty.

Comment: It's a fallacy to assume that the meaning of a word can necessarily be deduced through an analysis of its semantic constituents: the meanings of words are constantly evolving, and words that have a common root can evolve in very different directions. A word's etymology is at best a guide to its meaning, not a definitive predictor of it. In short, you're overthinking this.

Comment: @ErikKowal You're referring to the Etymological Fallacy, right? I do heed it, as I publicise in my profile, but I've been told by other users to omit it in my OP. Maybe I ought to repeat it in my posts.

Comment: In this case it is not a fallacy: the meaning is perfectly deduced trough a simple dissection of the elements.

Comment: No, don't! Don't repeat the mantra: [I heed the etymological fallacy](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A50720+heed+fallacy). @ErikKowal what have you done, after fifty posts of "I heed" you're now telling him to do that?! :))

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I guess I didn't see that mantra hidden in his profile. (Yes, heedless of me, I know... :)

Comment: @Mark - I think we have to distinguish between the post-hoc dissection of  of a compound word into its constituents, which often allows one to rationalize the word's current meaning; and the attempt to *predict* or *deduce* the meaning of a word from its constituent parts. The latter exercise is far more fraught with uncertainty and the possibility of error, partly for the reasons I gave before.

Comment: @Mark +1 to your answer. I apologise if you needed a faster response. I usually allow a short while before acceptance or supplementaries, because others may need more time. Please see my profile; I always return to my questions, but after time. But whenever you need a speedy reply, please just message me.

Comment: @Mark: Happy to clarify. I don't mind leaving my comment, unless you mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What's the meaning of 'pray' as bolded above? Is it the modern one of
>      prayer, or the olden one?
> 2. How did the 2 syntagma (ex- "out" + orare "pray") combine to mean exorare "to prevail upon,"? I don't understand this key link in the
>      etymology

- <sup>3</sup> *orare* means: 'to pray/beg/plead'
- <sup>2</sup> *ex* doesn't mean only *out*, but also: 'out of/ from/ because of' as in
- *ex-voto* = 'because of/from a vow',
- <sup>1</sup> *in* means: not,
- <sup>4</sup> *able* means: capable/possible, therefore:
- **in-ex-ora-ble** = [not]<sup>1</sup>  - [through/because of]<sup>2</sup> - [pleading/begging/ a prayer]<sup>3</sup> - [obtainable]<sup>4</sup>